# Eclipse JavaFX e4 application product build fails

Tags: java, maven, javafx, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm developing an JavaFX e4 application. So far I followed the [tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials) and I also got the example application up an running. I created a new project and included my code / views etc and the application works fine when started from eclipse. Now I want to export this app via maven, this is where I'm stuck.

I also need some external libraries, which are available as eclipse java projects. Some of these projects include Java code (like a selfwritten commons-lib) and others just include some jar files. Eclipse allows me include these projects via the `feature.xml` (just by clicking 'add').
So far everything works fine, when I start the app via the 'product' file and eclipse manages to resolve all dependencies and start my JavaFX e4 application without any errors.

When I try to build the application via maven from the terminal I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: mygui.app 1.0.0
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: mygui.app 1.0.0 requires 'bundle my.commom.vecmath 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from mygui.app 1.0.0 to bundle my.commom.vecmath 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from mygui.app 1.0.0 to bundle my.commom.vecmath 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.": ["Unable to satisfy dependency from mygui.app 1.0.0 to bundle my.commom.vecmath 0.0.0.", "No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable."]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.newResolutionException(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolveDependencies(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/InternalErrorException
```

The missing dependency is an eclipse Java project which includes some jars and some Java src files. Like I already said, eclipse manages to resolve the dependency and shows my GUI, maven is not able to resolve the dependency. I have no idea where the problem lies. First I thought of changeing the commons project to maven project with a proper configured `pom.xml` but without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all these years I found a solution for the problem. It was an malformed manifest, which has been created by maven (due to default values). See here for the solution [Maven: prefers manifest dependencies over pom.xml dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609943/maven-prefers-manifest-dependencies-over-pom-xml-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

The p2 repository your maven-tycho build points to (by default it is most likely only pointing to the efxclipse one) has to contain the required artifacts. Look at the pom.xml in the releng project!

We also provide support for e(fx)clipse via our forum https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/f/259/