# Maven: prefers manifest dependencies over pom.xml dependencies

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have project which requires one library. This lib is already in the local repro. I told the project through its `pom.xml` that it depends on this lib like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>de.mygui</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.mygui.app.releng</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../de.mygui.app.releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </parent>
   <groupId>de.mygui</groupId>
   <artifactId>de.mygui.map</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>common</groupId>
         <artifactId>my.util.geo</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

and the projects manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: gui map
Bundle-SymbolicName: de.mygui.map;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Import-Package: my.util.geo;version="2.0.0"
```

The `my.util.geo` manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Geo
Bundle-SymbolicName: my.util.geo
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Export-Package: my.util.geo
Require-Bundle: org.proj4j;bundle-version="0.1.0"
```

When running the parent POM to compile everything (also other required projects) I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: de.mygui.app.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: de.mygui.map 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'package my.util.geo 2.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: de.mygui.app.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: de.mygui.map 0.0.0
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.mygui:de.mygui.app.feature:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/myuser/dev/gui/de.mygui.app.feature/pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.MavenExecutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.mygui:de.mygui.app.feature:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/myuser/dev/gui/de.mygui.app.feature/pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:274)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.artifacts.DependencyResolutionException: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: de.mygui:de.mygui.app.feature:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /home/myuser/dev/gui/de.mygui.app.feature/pom.xml
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.doResolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(P2DependencyResolver.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoResolver.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:95)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ResolverException: See log for details
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.util.resolution.AbstractResolutionStrategy.resolve(AbstractResolutionStrategy.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveDependencies(P2ResolverImpl.java:195)
    ... 18 more
```

To me it looks like Maven looks first into the manifest and afterwards in the POM for its dependencies. As you can see I changed the version numbers of `my.util.geo` to verify that the manifest is used before the POM. Never the less even if I have the same versions in both the manifest and the POM, Maven is still not able to resolve the dependency.

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Comment: Can you show us the manifest of ``my.util.geo`` library ?

Comment: This erros seems to be related to the ``de.mygui.app.feature.feature.group``, can you also show us this ?

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis I added the my.util.geo manifest. the feature group is part of an RCP E4 build process. I don't think that hits is the problem. The whole build process worked until a few day ago. Back then all required projects (fodlers) were in one folder. But now started to separate them, so that the util projects are only accessible through maven and its local repro

Comment: what maven plugin is generated this error ?

Comment: Confirm that ``my.util.geo`` manifest's ``Bundle-Version: 1.0.0`` and ``de.gui.map`` manifest 's ``Import-Package: my.util.geo;version="2.0.0"`` instruction are just for test

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis How can I find out ? I'l use `tycho-maven-plugin` , `tycho-source-plugin` , `tycho-compiler-plugin` and `tycho-packaging-plugin` . I added the full stacktrace also

Comment: @AlexandreCartapanis yes they are just for test, when I change the 2.0 to 1.0 it still gives the error

Comment: Maybe you can try to modify the ``Export-Package`` to ``my.util.geo;version="2.0.0"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the `mainfest` of the jar (of `my.util.geo`) which was put into the local repro was the [default manifest](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html) of the [maven archiver](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/index.html). So I needed to edit my build script for `my.util.geo` lib to include all necessary values

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
         <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
         </manifest>
         <manifestEntries>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
            <Bundle-ClassPath>.</Bundle-ClassPath>
            <Export-Package>my.util.geo</Export-Package>
         </manifestEntries>
      </archive>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```